# Get different version with 'module load python' and 'python'

Tags: python, environment-modules

I found that when I just type `python` in the command line, I got *Python 2.7.9.* And when I type `module load python` and then `python` again, it gives me *Python 2.7.12 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)*, which is the version I need. Can anyone explain how it happens? And what can I do to make version 2.7.12 default when I simply type 'python'?

Comment: Where is the `module` command coming from? That's not part of Python itself, so I can't tell you how it's working. Can you elaborate a bit on what OS and Python distribution you're using?

Comment: I am working on a shared host (computer center). It should be a Linux system. And from what I learned from the web, module seems to be something that control different versions of software. I just use it on the command line, and not sure what it really is.

Answer (score 1):

firstly what do you mean "module load python" ?

another point, changing $PATH variable, you can set  default  python version.When you type  'python',terminal searches it in $PATH and  few various directory.Therefore remove path which refers old version in $PATH ,then add new path which refer to Python 2.7.12,For this use this

Place export declaration in ~/.bashrc.

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/u:$PATH
```

But the above solution may not work,thus use this simple way  alias.Like below

Place this into ~/.bashrc file

```
alias python=Python 2.7.12
```

Comment: Module is a command that can control different versions of software. I was told by others to use it on the command line, and not sure what it really is.

Comment: I think what you said is the correct answer, and it works.on personal computer. But I don't have permission to change the .bashrc files on the host. I am still searching for other solutions (maybe ask people in charge to do that)

Answer (score 1):

The [`module`](http://modules.sourceforge.net) command helps to activate/deactivate specific software version in your running shell. This command interprets scripts that are called *modulefiles* containing some environment definition to enable a specific version of a software, like for instance by altering the `PATH` variable.

You can learn what a modulefile does by displaying its content, in your situation:

```
$ module display python
```

The environment setup done by the `module` command is not persistent and it should be renewed if you start a new shell session. To get python `2.7.12` by default, you should edit your shell configuration file to automatically load this modulefile when shell is started.